# Matching routes from an array - Rails Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, match

I`m looking to implement links that fit a certain format (seo purposes).

Here`s an example:

```
match '/activities-Palmdale-California', :to => 'explores#activity_by_city', :location=>'Palmdale-California'
```

Where the location changes for each city+state.

Is there I way to dynamically loop through an array of cities & states (predefined) in the routes file, without creating additional models etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have parameters in your routes, so something like the following should work:

```rb
match "/activities-:location", :to => 'explores#activity_by_city'
```

and the `location` should be sent to your controller action in `params[:location]`. If you want to limit the urls your application will accept to just the locations in a predefined array (we'll call it `ValidLocations`), you can do it either in the route with the `:constraints` option:

```
match "/activities-:location", :to => 'explores#activity_by_city', :constraints => proc { |req| ValidLocations.include?(req.params[:location]) }
```

or in the controller:

```
def activity_by_city
  ...
  unless ValidLocations.include?(params[:location])
    flash[:error] = "Invalid location."
    redirect_to ...
    return
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Ok, but now how do I list all the cities & states in the controller if there in a simple array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You want to check if the `location` sent is in the predefined array?

Comment: I added a bit to my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Now I still have to pass the :location => 'city-state from array'. How do I access the the array & iterate through it in routes file ? Same way I would in a normal rb file?

Comment: @Big_Bird Yes, `routes.rb` is a regular Ruby file so you can iterate through an array the same way you would in any other file. But what are you doing the iteration for?

Comment: I have an array of the cities & states which I would like to list. Something like @locations = ['Neverland, OH', 'Gotham, New York'].

Comment: @Big_Bird Right, so like the `ValidLocations` array I'm using in my examples. Can you explain to me what the problem with that is?

Comment: I think he's got the impression that if it does not exist in the routes file, the link does not exist (thus would hurt his SEO).